# javaScript - changing values of location input field on google calendar

Tags: javascript, input

As part of a chrome extension for Google calendar I develop, I want to change the "Add location" input field on a google calendar meeting event (https://calendar.google.com/calendar/b/0/r/eventedit?tab=mc).

So far I've tried the following:

```
let locationInputField = document.querySelector('[aria-label="Location"]');
locationInputField.value = 'Meeting Place';
locationInputField.dispatchEvent(new Event("input", { bubbles: true }));
```

Although the value does change, once I save the meeting event the location text ('Meeting Place') is not saved and remains empty.

I've searched for additional optional solutions and also tried using `.focus()` and `.select()` but no success there also.

Appreciate your help. 
Thanks!

Comment: What is the purpose of your add-on - does this have to be done through the use of front-end manipulation or is using the API a viable solution? Creating events directly through the Google Calendar API is much easier and securer than attempting to edit the DOM, and using the `querySelector` method to obtain the form elements is bad practice as the aria labels could be changed at any time rendering your code not working.

Comment: @rafa Thanks. The purpose of the add-on is to assist with scheduling rooms for meetings and the only engagement with the google calendar's DOM is to place the Meeting Room name in the appropriate place (location input field). So, IMHO, I don't want nor need to work with the official API.

Comment: Manipulating the DOM directly like this, honestly, isn't the way to go. The calendar pages are dynamic, as you can see by inspecting the source of the pages, and so labels and IDs change all the time without any prior warning which will render your add-on to not work and constantly need updating. The existence of the APIs are exactly for this kind of functionality, and I can't stress enough how it would be better to manipulate the event this way.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo I'll take your feedback into considerations (in a nutshell, that means that my future users (as may be the case) will have to provide my add-on/extension with access to their calendar which is not the current case). Nevertheless, I think that we are missing the point here.  The question is about working with an input field on google's calendar web page and the fact that it cannot be changed and saved.

Comment: `The question is about working with an input field on google's calendar web page and the fact that it cannot be changed and saved.` - because it's not meant to be, this is why it's dynamic in nature. I don't want to give you bad advice for your project, especially some which will likely stop working in the forseeable future.